# profile setting to have access to the recall button

Tags: profile, permission-sets, approval-process, user-profile

I have been restructuring Profiles and I have just run into an issue. I switched one of my users and now she does not have the "recall" action on the approval history view. She is an approver and needs this action available to her. I switched her back to her old profile and logged in as her to confirm that this is a result of some profile setting. I'm not sure what controls this and am having no luck in my research/troubleshooting. Does anyone know which setting(s) she needs to have this action?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration for recalling an approval is on the process itself.

> If you submitted a record for approval but suddenly need to update information in the record, recall the approval request. However, **whether you can recall an approval request depends on how your admin configured the approval process** that the record was submitted to.

You can find the processes in your org by navigating to *Setup > Process Automation > Approval Processes*.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=approvals_users_recall.htm&type=5

Comment: That's what I thought too which is why I'm confused. The approval process nor the approver has changed. The only thing I changed was the profile for this user. I have confirmed that switching her back to her old profile gives her access to the recall action and the new profile does not.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that the user needs Modify All on the object that the approval process is on (Opportunity object in my case). This has resolved my question and given the recall action back to the user on the new profile using a permission set for the additional access.

Comment: But actually your user only needs the "read" permission on the object (as stated on the documentation). This is implied when you give them the "modify all" permission. You previously said that the user was an approver, but that does not mean that she should be able to recall the request. What determines a user's ability to recall the request is the checkbox on the 6th stage while configuring the approval process ("Submission Settings" > "Allow submitters to recall approval requests").